# EST and EDT time Return GMT time in java

Tags: java

When i perform :

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EDT"));
```

or

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));
```

and get the time zone :

```
System.out.println(TimeZone.getDefault());
```

I get time in GMT. 
Or if you can tell me what is the full name i can pass instead of the abbreviated names like EST and EDT. Full name like "AMerica/New-York".

I want to display the EST time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try setting the time zone using `America/New_York`:

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
System.out.println(TimeZone.getDefault());
```

This prints:

```
sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="America/New_York",offset=-18000000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=235,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=America/New_York,offset=-18000000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=3,startMonth=2,startDay=8,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=7200000,startTimeMode=0,endMode=3,endMonth=10,endDay=1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=7200000,endTimeMode=0]]
```

Perhaps a side note:

You can list all available timezone id's using:

```
String[] ids = TimeZone.getAvailableIDs();
for (String id : ids) {
    System.out.println(TimeZone.getTimeZone(id).getID());
}
```